# multi level inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, multi-level

Suppose there is a 3 level inheritance.

Classes A<-B<-C.

Can methods of B class access members of C which is derived from it?

Assume suitable mode of inheritance.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: What happened when you tried it out?

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote. The answer is obviously no, but... and the answer is appropriate in that regard.

Comment: **Books:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 5):

A parent class cannot access data from a child class without "tricks", e.g.

```
class A
{
protected:
  int m_a;
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
  int m_b;
};
```

B can access m_a, A cannot access m_b. To get this behaviour you can use polymorphism and an accessor function

```
class A
{
protected:
  virtual int GetVar() { return m_a; }
private:
  int m_a;
}

class B : public A
{
protected:
  virtual int GetVar() { return m_b; }
private:
  int m_b;
}
```

Now A can access m_b through calling `GetVar()` e.g.

```
void A::DoSomething()
{
  // I want to do something to the variable, 
  int myVar = GetVar();
}
```

Now if the instance is type `A` then `A::GetVar()` is called, if the instance is type `B` then `B::GetVar()` will be called instead